# Not able to save data from Firebase database to an Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*I'm fairly new to swift

I'm currently using Swift 4, Xcode 9, and Firebase. My goal is to create an app that stores data in a list, displays it in a table view, and allows the user to add more data to the list. I'm stuck on the displaying data part, I created a function that is supposed to get the data from the database, then add it into an array so that I can display individual parts of it on a custom table view cell. Here's my code:

```
class OrdersPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return orders.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "orderCell", for: indexPath) as! OrderCell
    cell.setOrder(order: orders[indexPath.row])
    print("Adding new cell")
    return cell
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var orders = [Order]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    orders = getOrders()
}

func getOrders() -> [Order] {
    var tempArray = [Order]()
    ref.child("Orders").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let orderDB = child as! DataSnapshot
            let orderDict = orderDB.value as! [String: Any]

            let name = orderDict["name"] as! String
            let date = orderDict["date"] as! String
            let time = orderDict["time"] as! String
            let hotel = orderDict["hotel"] as! String
            let room = orderDict["room"] as! String
            let airport = orderDict["airport"] as! String
            let agent = orderDict["agent"] as! String
            let price = orderDict["price"] as! String
            //let submitted = orderDict["submitted"] as! String
            tempArray.append(Order(name: name, date: date, time: time, hotel: hotel, room: room, airport: airport, agent: agent, price: price))
        }
    }
    return tempArray
}
```

Based off of my testing, the issue is that the orders array doesn't contain anything when the numberOfRowsInSection is called so it doesn't create any cells in the table view. I'm not sure why it's not working as it should and have been stuck on this for quite some time now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you able to get data in your snapshot or array please print your array when you got your values.

Comment: Yes, in my testing I tried printing the individual values it's supposed to add into the array and it printed them.

Comment: okay then please check delegates of your tableview are attached and after adding value in array please reload your tableview to show data in tableview

Comment: is my answer helped you ?

Comment: No, the issue was that I didn't reload the table view after adding data to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOrders()` is Asynchronous call so you need to reload your table after you got data from server.

Here is the way you can achieve that.

Replace:

```
func getOrders() -> [Order]
```

with

```
func getOrders()
```

And your `getOrders` method will look like:

```
func getOrders() {

    ref.child("Orders").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let orderDB = child as! DataSnapshot
            let orderDict = orderDB.value as! [String: Any]

            let name = orderDict["name"] as! String
            let date = orderDict["date"] as! String
            let time = orderDict["time"] as! String
            let hotel = orderDict["hotel"] as! String
            let room = orderDict["room"] as! String
            let airport = orderDict["airport"] as! String
            let agent = orderDict["agent"] as! String
            let price = orderDict["price"] as! String
            //let submitted = orderDict["submitted"] as! String

            //Add your data into array
            self.orders.append(Order(name: name, date: date, time: time, hotel: hotel, room: room, airport: airport, agent: agent, price: price))
        }

        //Reload your tableView here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I have updated inner code. Check comments.

Now in your `viewDidLoad` method Replace:

```
orders = getOrders()
```

With

```
getOrders()
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didSet` during define your variable of `self.orders` for reloading `UITableView`

Here your table will automatically reload when any data is assigned to `self.orders`

Replace your declaration

```
var orders = [Order]()
```

with below code

```
var orders : [Order] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```